# How to fetch special char with five digits no in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I am trying to fetch :with five digits no values in oracle.
my data look this format.

```
this :years 2016 only department :12345
aign:BR-PESP-THELIMITED-:30510
:thiss and :years 2016 only department :12345
travel visa :34322 LLL001
```

i am using this query

> substring(check1,regexp_instr(check1,':'),6)

```
my current o/p:
years
BR-PE
thiss
34322

my expected o/p 
12345
30510
12345
34322
```

Comment: What are you trying to return?

Comment: :12345,then next row 30510,then next row 12345 then next row 34322

Comment: Is this one string or a column? Can you please [edit] your question to contain _exactly_ what you want returned?

Comment: is one column only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return the five digits after a colon:

```
select regexp_substr(check1, ':([0-9]{5})', 1, 1)
```

Comment: getting this error
 ERROR: function regexp_substr(character varying, "unknown", integer, integer) does not exist

Comment: @Velu are you sure you're running this on oracle?